# How to redirect users to the right site when using variations?

Tags: redirect, variations

I am currently using SharePoint 2013 On-Premise and I have enabled the Variations in a site collection.

Under the site collection, three sub sites are created for each language.
My question is: how can I redirect the user to the right language when he/she visits the site? Does SharePoint handle this based on user's Browser settings, do I have to write any custom code to handle redirection or configure something in web.config?

**Edit**

I have changed the language in the browser to French, but I am still not redirected to the French site when I visit my site: `http://dev/sites/heli`,for example.

Comment: SharePoint handle this based on Browser language settings. Try set other language in browser.

Comment: I changed the language to French, but I am not redirected to the sub site. I still remain in the root site which is in English. (http://dev/sites/heli).

I should be redirected to http://dev/sites/heli/french.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enable variations in your site collection, there is a file created in the pages Library called: `VariationRoot.aspx`. When you open this file, you will be redirected to the write site.

You have to set this page as your home page, so that everytime a user visits your site, he will be redirected to the correct site.

You can set it has homepage either in 1) `SharePoint Designer` or you can use 2) `PowerShell`.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect is based on users browser settings (out of the box) but this behaviour can be overridden based on users profile language preferences (require customization)

Comment: yes, I got it so far that it is done out of the box based on the user's language specified in the browser, but why then it does not work in my case? I have created a site collection, then I enabled variations and there I have three subsites for each language. I change the language to French, but I am not redirected to the correct site. What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c2c8d72d-45f0-4c34-936d-3bdabec68b14/autoredirect-to-self-enrollment-portal-when-logging-into-site-protected-with-multi-factor?forum=windowsazureactiveauthentication
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/20b5793a-cfeb-4105-956c-a0302676c8ea/redirect-to-user-to-particular-subsite-based-upon-view-only-permission-on-parent-site-?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7915acd4-8240-4cc2-8465-fdb8811d7529/workflow-to-redirect-user-to-another-page

I guess there's no other way, you will need to code.

Bests Regards!