# Can we use sharepoint online root site as source variation

Tags: sharepoint-online, variations, multilingual

Hi we are now working in multi language in SharePoint and we need to set the root site as source instead of its sub site.

I read that in variation we need to set the en-US as main source but in our case it needs to be the global root site because other countries has specific contents.

Below is our structure

```
company.sharepoint.com <---Root / Global
                      /US  <---Unit States
                      /China  <--- China 
                      /Italy
```

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible since it would introduce overlap between labels / the navigation hierarchy.

There are many methods to redirect users from different countries to the right site when using variations, you can check this article:

[How to redirect users to the right site when using variations?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166882/how-to-redirect-users-to-the-right-site-when-using-variations)

Answer (score 0):

Variations are build on subsites. You cant make the root itself a variation, since that will be the variation root site. Below will be the different variation labels in the hierarchy.

There is a (fairly old) post by Steffan which explains this in a lot of detail:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2011/11/14/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-1-the-basics/